# Array prints multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to print every element in the array that occurs multiple times, and what index they´re on. 
*For example: Tall(Number): 2, index: 0*
However, I only want it to print out *once* per index. Sorry for the bad explanation and that it's in Norwegian!

```
<!Doctype html>
<HTML lang="no">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>#</title>
    <script>
        window.onload = oppstart;

        function oppstart() {
            var heltall = [2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
            var utskrift = "-- \n";

            for (j = 0; j < heltall.length; j++) {
                var talletViSkalTelle = heltall[j];
                for (i = 0; i < heltall.length; i++) {
                    if (heltall[i] == talletViSkalTelle) {
                        utskrift += "Tall: " + talletViSkalTelle + ", index: " + i + "\n";
                    }
                }
            }
            print(utskrift);
        }

        function print(text) {
            var el = document.getElementById("utskrift");
            el.innerText = text;
            //el = element//
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>

<p id="utskrift"></p>

</body>
```

Comment: So, why don't you keep an additional array for the elements you've already printed, add something there if the element is printed and check for it before printing the next element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array which stores numbers which you have already gone through then checks that array if the next number has already been stored before iterating again.

See below working snippet

```html
<!Doctype html>
<HTML lang="no">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>#</title>
    <script>
        window.onload = oppstart;
        var pushed = [];

        function oppstart() {
            var heltall = [2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
            var utskrift = "-- \n";

            for (j = 0; j < heltall.length; j++) {
                var talletViSkalTelle = heltall[j];
                if(!check(talletViSkalTelle)){
                  pushed.push(talletViSkalTelle);
                  for (i = 0; i < heltall.length; i++) {
                      if (heltall[i] == talletViSkalTelle) {
                          utskrift += "Tall: " + talletViSkalTelle + ", index: " + i + "\n";
                      }
                  }
                }
            }
            print(utskrift);
        }

        function print(text) {
            var el = document.getElementById("utskrift");
            el.innerText = text;
            //el = element//
        }
        
        function check(num){
          for(var i = 0; i<pushed.length; i++){
            if(num === pushed[i]){
              return true;
            }
          }
          return false;
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>

<p id="utskrift"></p>

</body>
```

Comment: Instead of the `check()` function, the included `includes` method could be used.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create an array to store the numbers you have already processed, let's say:

```
var tallerViHarTellet = []
```

after your initialization of your heltall array.

Then, check if the number was already checked, like this:

```
if (tallerViHarTellet.includes(talletViSkalTelle))continue;
tallerViHarTellet.push(tallerViSkalTelle)
```

after

```
var talletViSkalTelle = heltall[j];
```

That way, you will skip checking numbers you already checked.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to print all array repeating element separately with different index at they occurs? or you need repeating array elements with all index at which they occurs?

```
<!Doctype html>
<HTML lang="no">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>#</title>
    <script>
        window.onload = oppstart;

        function getIndices (arr){
          var out = {};
          arr.map((tall, idx) => {
              if(out.hasOwnProperty(tall)) {
                  out[tall].push(idx)
              } else { 
                  out[tall] = [idx]
              }
          })
          return out;
        }

        function oppstart() {
            var heltall = [2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
            var utskrift = "-- \n";
            var res = getIndices(heltall);

            Object.keys(res).map(function(tall){
            if (res[tall].length > 1) {
                utskrift += "Tall: " + tall + ", indices: " + res[tall].join(', ') + "\n";
            }
            })
            print(utskrift);
        }

        function print(text) {
            var el = document.getElementById("utskrift");
            el.innerText = text;
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>

<p id="utskrift"></p>

</body>
```

OutPut

```
-- 
Tall: 1, indices: 6, 9
Tall: 2, indices: 0, 5, 8, 11
Tall: 3, indices: 1, 3, 12
Tall: 4, indices: 2, 7, 10, 13
Tall: 5, indices: 4, 14
```